# Entity create foreign key

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, entity

I am trying to add a foreign key relationship using entity and code first. I have the following simplified setup.

```
public class ChildClass
{
    public int SId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SId")]
    public ParentClass Parent { get; set; }
}

public class ParentClass
{       
    [Key]
    public int SId { get; set; }      
    public ChildClass Child { get; set; }
}
```

When I try and add my migration, I get the following error.

```
Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'ChildClass' and 'ParentClass'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.
```

Comment: Try putting `"ParentClass"` instead of `"SId"`

Comment: Aren't annotations supposed to be above the declarartion?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `SId` property in your `ChildClass` to be the PK as well as FK, you should try this :

```
    public class ChildClass
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("Parent")]
        public int SId { get; set; }

        public ParentClass Parent { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParentClass
    {
        [Key]
        public int SId { get; set; }

        public ChildClass Child { get; set; }
    }
```

The tables that are created :

**Parent :**

[image]

**Child :**

[image]